# WEB API call stops working after introducing the "await" keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, c#-5.0

I have a simple web api method which retrieves a list of items from a database. When the method looks like this it works and the items are displayed in the UI:

```
[ActionName("GetServices")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetServices()
{
    var services = dbContext.Service.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(services);
}
```

But as soon as I introduce the `await` keyword to the method it stops working(if i put a break point on the method it still gets hit but nothing is displayed on the UI):

```
[ActionName("GetServices")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetServices()
{
    var services = await dbContext.Service.ToListAsync();
    return Ok(services);
}
```

Comment: your first sample is returning a `Task` object, because you aren't `await`ing the results. The second is correct. You could change the first sample to `dbContext.Service.ToListAsync().Wait();`

Comment: Are you sure your first example is correct and working?

Comment: await essentially means that you are making the runtime to wait until the method is executed.  The first code snippet returns a task object while the second returns the actual services from db. Since you are saying that with first code block it displays the services you must be awaiting that task object in your UI layer. Did you change your UI layer code when you put await there?

Comment: What response status you get?  I guess, an exception was thrown after call `var services = await dbContext.Service.ToListAsync();`

Comment: Show us how you're invoking `GetServices()`

Comment: @shwetaOnStack you are right, after adding await i had to change my javascript to bind directly to the response instead of response.Result.Could you please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Use tools such as Postman for chrome, or Fiddler2 to diagnose issues with routes. They will determine whether its client side fault of server side fault.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"await" essentially means that you are making the runtime to wait until the method is executed. The first code snippet returns a task object while the second returns the actual services from db. Since you are saying that with first code block it displays the services you must be awaiting that task object in your UI layer. You must change your UI layer code after you put await in the WEB API.

Comment: can anyone explain the downvotes? It seems to have worked for the person posting the question and he asked me to put my comment in the answer. So what it is that the downvoters don't like about this answer?